# Не срабатывает Required в TypedDict

Tags: python

Читаю [PEP 655](https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/) о пометках отдельных элементов TypedDict'a
Код следующий:

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from typing import Required

class Point(TypedDict, total = False): 
    x: int 
    y: Required[int]

t1: Point = {'x': 18}
t2 = Point(x = '20')

print(t1) # {'x': 18}
print(t2) # {'x': '20'}
```

Я ожидаю, что программа будет "ругаться" на мой код, ведь я передаю всего один аргумент в то время, когда обязательный ещё и Y. Почему это работает? Как сделать аргумент обязательным?

P.S. И почему пропускает строковый тип? X же аннотирован как int

Comment: Программа ругаться и не должна, ругаться должны линтеры

Comment: @andreymal IDE в коде никаких индикаторов/подчёркиваний и прочего тоже не выявил. Всё работает в штатном режиме. Использую VSCode. Из линтеров - Python и Pylance (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)

Comment: Ну тогда это уже вопросы к Pylance, а к примеру mypy и pyright вполне выводят три ошибки

Comment: @andreymal Поставил pyright и увидел изменения. Большое спасибо, помогло